# Criação de vetor em c++

Tags: c++

O que signifia o `new int[2]` em

`int* vetor = new int[2];`

Comment: Será alocada uma área de memória que comporta 2 int e vetor apontará para o início desta área.

Comment: É uma forma embutida na linguagem de fazer malloc(2 * sizeof(int)), que é como se faria em C.

Answer (score 2):

Significa que você esta criando um vetor de 2 posições, o valor dentro dos colchetes indica o tamanho que você quer utilizar para a criação do vetor.